# Rails 4 Error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

Hey there,
I am fairly new to Rails and I've managed to create a Favorite controller for my Items(Tools) and Users.
 I am displaying all Favorited Items(Tools) by a user correctly on his index. On the search view I provide links to favorite and unfavorite, but I am getting an error when I click on this link of a certain Item(Tool)

**I am getting this error in the browser when favoriting an item:**

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ToolsController#favorite
Tool(#46153692) expected, got NilClass(#20297664)
```

*The Request Parameters*

```
{"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"vlWYHcp1K4Eu8WzjyEM8f6Eta9MNjgojtkr6RlG6n7121PGiWtXU8kDq9yXOfzGzw5grSc4GCqlcoK1UiLEsng==",
 "type"=>"favorite", #WhatMyUserDid
 "id"=>"1"} #MyUserId
```

My goal is to *add a favorited Item(Tool)* for a User **(=> Error)**, *show favorited Items(Tools)* on Users index view **(works fine)**, and *show the link* to Favorite or Unfavorite *depending on the Favorites of the current_user* **(not implemented yet)**

**Here is my code:**

*app/models/favorite_tool.rb*

```
class FavoriteTool < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tool
    belongs_to :user
end
```

*app/models/tool.rb*

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    # Favorited by users
    has_many :favorite_tools # just the 'relationships'
    has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_tools, source: :user # the actual users favoriting a tool


    mount_uploader :cover_filename, CoverUploader
end
```

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:

  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  has_many :tools

  # Favorite tools of user
  has_many :favorite_tools # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_tools, source: :tool # the actual tools the user favorites


  mount_uploader :avatar_filename, AvatarUploader

end
```

*app/controllers/tools_controller.rb*

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_tool, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # Add and remove favorite recipes
    # for current_user
    def favorite
        type = params[:type]
        if type == "favorite"
            current_user.favorites << @tool
            redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@tool.title}'

        elsif type == "unfavorite"
            current_user.favorites.delete(@tool)
            redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@tool.title}'

        else
            # Type missing, nothing happens
            redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
        end
    end

    def index
        @favorites = current_user.favorites
        @tools = Tool.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
        @user = current_user
    end

    def search
        @tool = Tool.find(1)
        @tools = Tool.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @tool = current_user.tools.build
    end

    def create
        @tool = current_user.tools.build(tool_params)

        if @tool.save
            redirect_to tools_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @tool.update(tool_params)
            redirect_to tools_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @tool.destroy
        redirect_to tools_path
    end

    private

    def find_tool
        @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tool_params
        params.require(:tool).permit(:title, :subtitle, :url, :cover_filename)
    end
end
```

*app/views/tools/index.html.haml*

```
%h2 My Favorite Tools
- @favorites.each do |tool|
    = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)
```

*app/views/tools/search.html.haml*

```
- @tools.each do |tool|
    = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= link_to tool.user.try(:username), '/users/'+tool.user_id.to_s
    %p= link_to "Favorite", favorite_tool_path(@tool, type: "favorite"), method: :put
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", favorite_tool_path(@tool, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)
```

*app/config/routes.rb*

```
resources :tools do
  put :favorite, on: :member
end
```

I hope the provided data is enough, if not please tell me. I'm grateful for all Your replies.

Comment: It is possible that Tools.find is returning nil. Can you post the logs? Or better, can you post the output of `Tools.find(1)`?

Comment: @Umang Raghuvanshi How am I able to do this?

Comment: In your app's directory, run `rails c`. You'll get an interactive console and then just run the command I gave.

Comment: @Umang Raghuvanshi Ah that's what you meant. I ran this and it gave me an error. But I think 'Tool.find(1)' is the thing we need here. If I type in that, I get the data of this Item as usual

Comment: I also added the relevant stuff from the routes.rb file to the post

Comment: That is what I get: irb(main):003:0> Tool.find(1)
  Tool Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tools".* FROM "tools" WHERE "tools"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Tool id: 1, title: "xfgjxfgjrdthdrth", subtitle: " tzkfftzkftzfz", url: "tdfzjftzj", shares: 0, views: 0, likes: 0, favorites: 0, created_at: "2016-09-04 10:33:43", updated_at: "2016-09-04 10:34:09", user_id: 1, cover_filename: nil>
irb(main):004:0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `before_action` needs to include `:favorite` as you are not defining the `@tool` in your `favorite` action.

Comment: That worked - cool, thank you! Do you know a way to check whether the item is favorited by the current_user or not and then, depending on that, show either 'Favorite' or 'Unfavorite'?